# How to split the string and construct as array of objects in rails?

Tags: ruby, json, split

I have a string like

```
{"a":1, "b":1, "c":1}{"a":2, "b":2, "c":2}
```

I wanted to parse the string using

```
JSON.parse(data)
```

but I get parse error, so I want to split this and process. How can I split this into two separate data and parse?

I need something like

```
["{"a":1, "b":1, "c":1}", "{"a":2, "b":2, "c":2}"]
```

so that I can loop and parse. How can I do this? Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### 1)Your current string is:

```
a = '{"a":1, "b":1, "c":1}{"a":2, "b":2, "c":2}'
```

---

#### 2)You can use the `gsub` method to replace some characters, adding some special character `$`:

```
b = a.gsub( "}{" , "}${" )
```

Now `b` will be:

```
'{"a":1, "b":1, "c":1}${"a":2, "b":2, "c":2}'
```

---

#### 3)Finally you can split on the special character you picked (`$`).

```
c = b.split("$")
```

The value of `c` will be:

```
["{"a":1, "b":1, "c":1}", "{"a":2, "b":2, "c":2}"]
```